# How to create an update method for an android 3D game framework?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, opengl-es

I have been trying to create an android 3D game using http://www.jpct.net/ which uses opengl to render 3D graphics easily.

My question is how would I go about creating an update method for the gamestate using a 3D framework?

I know the Android Activity class has these commands which involve using a glsurface view:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
}

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent me) {

}
```

Then the GLSurfaceView.Renderer class has these methods.

```
class MyRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {


    public MyRenderer() {
    }

    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int w, int h) {
    }

    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
    }

    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    }
}
```

Although I am able to use the jpct tutorial to draw images, respond to them and calculate frame rate, it doesn't call an update method or have a way to ensure a near constant frame rate because it handles its user input checking in the onTouchEvent method, while my game that needs to be updated when not touching the screen.

Does anybody have any advice on how to ensure an update method is called and handled with the onDrawFrame method? I think it would involve generating a second thread which calls update, but I wouldn't know how to guarantee it being properly synchronized with the onDrawFrame method. Does anyone have any advice on how to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

onDrawFrame() will be called by Android anyway. Just put your game logic into that method. You shouldn't use another thread to do this, because you'll run into synchronization issues between your game logic and the rendering.

Comment: I had separate threads and it worked until I wanted to synchronize between the GLThread (the one `onDrawFrame` is called in) and one of my own threads: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11639734/synchronized-with-glthread-in-android