# Synchronized with GLThread in Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, opengl-es, synchronized

I'm making a game in android using opengl-es, using multiple threads:

```
class World{

    protected static final AtomicInteger entityLock = new AtomicInteger();

    private GameEntity entities[];

    public World(){
        // populate game world with entities
        // executed on main thread
        addEntity(new GameEntity("tank"));
        addEntity(new GameEntity("rifleman"));
        addEntity(new GameEntity("rifleman"));
    }

    void update(){
        synchronized(entityLock){
           for(int i = 0;i<entities.length;i++){
                // move entity to new position
                // executed on PhysThread
                entities[i].updatePosition();                    
            }
        }
        if(entity.isDead(){
            // remove entity. Enter sync block inside removeEntity() method
            removeEntity(entity);                  
        }                      
    }

    void draw(GL10 gl){
        synchronized(entityLock){
            for(int i = 0;i<entites.length;i++){
                // draw models
                // executed on GLThread
                Vector3 entityPosition = entities[i].getPosition();
                gl.glTranslatef(entityPosition.x, entityPosition.y, entityPosition.z);
                entities[i].draw();
            }
        }
    }

    public void addEntity(GameEntity entity){
        synchronized(entityLock){
            // arrays stuff
        }
    }

    public void removeEntity(GameEntity entity){
        synchronized(entityLock){
            // arrays stuff
        }
    }

} 

class MyRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer{

    World world;

    public MyRenderer(World world){
        this.world = world;
    }


    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        // executed on GLThread
        world.draw(gl);             
    }


}

class PhysThreadRunnable implements Runnable{

    private long tickRate = 30;

    private World world;

    private PhysThreadRunnable(World world){
        this.world = world;
    }

    protected void setTickRate(long tickRate){
        this.tickRate = tickRate;
    }

    public void run() {
        while(true){                
            try {
                // executed on PhysThread
                world.update();
                Thread.sleep(1000/tickRate);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                return;
            }

        }
    }
}

MyActivity extends Activity{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        World world = new World(); 
        // sets up the game world, populates it with entities

        // set up GLSurfaceView (simplified)
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        GLSurfaceView mGLView = findViewById(R.id.myGLSurfaceView);
        mGLView.setRenderer(new MyRenderer(world));

        // start phys thread
        PhysThreadRunnable physThreadRunnable = new PhysThreadRunnable(world);
        Thread physThread = new Thread(physThreadRunnable);
        physThread.start();
    }
}
```

I have a problem where sometimes (but not every time) when I start the game, the PhysThread gets stuck waiting for the lock to be released (i.e. when I go to debug and pause the thread, it is just sat on `synchronized(entityLock)` inside `update()`

What's really strange is that after a while (between 2 seconds and a minute), the PhysThread will be unblocked, and the game will continue without either thread getting locked out for more than a few iterations of the thread loops. (i.e. the game runs fine)

**Edit:** I added some extra stuff to the example, just in case that is the cause of the problem. Basically, updating and drawing an array of entities rather than a single entity

Comment: Use LibGDX instead. It already integrates with openGL and box2d. Its also quite low level. Check it out and see how much time I just saved you.

Comment: Well the code above is just example code. I already spent about a year making my engine. So starting over is not really on the cards. I just want to know if this is a general synchronization issue or something specific to Android's GLSurfaceView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I went for the cheat solution. I put the synchronization blocks around access to the entities array and put the for loops inside a try/catch with ArrayIndexOutOfBounds:

```
void update(){
    try{
        for(int i = 0;i<entities.length;i++){               
            GameEntity entity = entities[i];                
            synchrnonized(entity){
                entity.updatePosition();
            }               
        }
    }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException aioob){
        if(tryAgain){
            update();
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with this solution is that if `entity.updateposition()` throws an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` from something completely unrelated, then I'll catch it and misinterpret it. Plus the whole thing is a bit messy, and once in every while, a frame or update gets skipped

As this appears to solved the problem, I suspect the original cause probably lies somewhere deeper in my code, between entering the for loops and actually modifying the entities, and I don't really think it'd be fair to dump my entire code here.

I'll leave the question unanswered for a couple days in case anyone else has a better solution

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue here is probably that there is no fairness guaranteed by the 'synchronized' block.

The OpenGL thread will always be rendering continuously, so it will attempt to reenter onDraw as soon as it finishes it. Since the choice of which thread is allowed to enter the synchronized block is arbitrary, it could be possible that the OpenGL thread attempts to reacquire the lock before it is released to the physics thread, and based on some arbitrary criteria it is given the lock over and over without allowing the physics thread to enter.

This might explain why it happens sometime and not others, since it is an arbitrary decision.

You might try implementing a fair lock instead of a synchronization block, or making it such that the OpenGL does not attempt to redraw the scene more than once since the last physics update (put the render thread to sleep until an update has occured).

Comment: I don't think that's correct. 1. The waiting sync (physics thread) will acquire the lock before ondraw finishes and 2. It takes a while for the gl thread to call ondrawframe again because it's busy rendering (this happens after ondrawframe exits).

Comment: I could sleep the GLThread until the physics update has finished. But then I might as well put everything in one thread. Different things will update at different times in the game. For example, I might introduce a third thread that updates the factories in the game to produce and consume once a second, and give it a lower priority. Or when the game pauses, it would be easy to just pause the physics thread, but leave the GLThread running so players can still pan the camera, zoom etc